# Access a pattern inside a complex name

Tags: python

I need to assign to all entries of a list (L) a special acronym they contain that is delimited by two underscore symbols and build a list out of them (S). An excerpt is below.

```
L = ['13058_8pcw_Ocx_M', '13058_8pcw_M1C-S1C_M' , '13058_8pcw_AMY_F']
S = ['Ocx','M1C-S1C','AMY']
```

I made many tries including regular expressions but I failed to get what I want. Ideally one would build a loop to create the list S and use regular expressions to access the particular acronym in L.

Can somebody provide some support or a solution ? Thanks.

Comment: What regex did you try? it seems something like `[^_]+_[^_]+_(.+)_M` might work for your example or are there other possible patterns?

Comment: Thanks. I corrected the post. Appart from _M there can be also _F. I tried this regex: `pattern = r'_([a-zA-Z]+)_'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use re.findall.
NB The second element has 2 matches for `_[^_]+_` so we have only taken the last one, as per your expected output.

```
import re
L = ['13058_8pcw_Ocx_M', '13058_8pcw_M1C-S1C_M' , '13058_8pcw_AMY_M']
S = []
for l in L:
  S.append(re.findall(r'_([^_]+)_[^_]*$',l)[0])

print(S)
```

output

```
['Ocx', 'M1C-S1C', 'AMY']
```

The regex pattern is looking for any character except underscore (`^` for not) between 2 underscores. The square brackets indicate a class and the `+` means that it is repeated 1 or more times.
The part within the brackets `(...)` is the capturing group, which is returned by the function findall as a list so we use `[0]` to get the first element.
After `_([^_]+)_` we have   `[^_]*$` which is any number `*` of any character except underscore before the end of the string `$`.

Comment: It worked fine. Many thanks indeed. Can you explain the meaning of all those symbols ?